# how to calculate the total power dissipation of below circuit

Tags: power-electronics, power-dissipation

[image]

how to calculate the total power dissipation of below circuit

Comment: You start the simulation and add up all the power readings from all power sources...

Answer (score 3):

Take the sum of all the supply voltages multiplied by the respective currents that they supply. You can do this in LTSpice by using {formula} such as: -

AVG(V1*I(V1))

That gives you the average power provided by V1 and, in case there are negative supplies you might be able to use ABS(x) to make the average powers all positive.

You just plot it and look at the graph.

That's how I remember doing it when I once used LTSpice so, if I've got something wrong in the ABS or AVG bits I apologize right now.

Comment: i didn't use LTspice.. at the moment my role is to calculate the total heat dissipation of the above circuit and implement it in practically also... so i have to calculate manually

Comment: What package produced the circuit diagram @Raj_1

Answer (score 0):

the biggest power sources are:

{4 to} 20mA*15V= 300mW
Vb+^2/330=  xx mW for bridge.

Next question ... is 15 necessary? or how small do you want Pd?

Answer (score 0):

Add a current meter in series with V1, V3 and V5. Then multiply each voltage/current pair, then make an adder/low-pass filter for the 3 multipliers. The output will be the average total power. (This assumes no power dissipation due to signal sources.)

Comment: thanks for your comments... but how to find the power dissipation for the actual circuit... is that can find... i just confused?

Comment: @Raj_1 - The only way to find the power for the _actual_ circuit is to build it and measure. Anything else involves using a model of the circuit, and as the saying goes, "All models are inaccurate. Some are useful."